# Apart from the Master, Which part can be used as a SYNC message sender in CANopen?

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I encountered a problem, the message that goes from the NMT to the nodes for synchronization is usually done through the Master in CANopen.

Can another department do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to clear out some terms:

- NMT = Network Management, a protocol used in CANopen.
- Master = NMT master, the node responsible for supervision and initiating state changes of other nodes. Outside of NMT, there is no master.

Therefore the sentence "the message that goes from the NMT to the nodes" doesn't make any sense and has nothing to with the SYNC message either.

The SYNC feature is a feature of its own, related to PDOs rather than NMT. Nodes have SYNC producer or SYNC consumer capabilities. For convenience, it is often the NMT Master acting as SYNC producer, but this isn't a requirement by the standard. Any node supporting the SYNC producer feature can act as one.

(Not to be confused with Heartbeat producer/consumer, which *is* part of NMT.)

For reference see Object Dictionary entries 1005h to 1007h, CiA 301 chapter 7.5.2.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a problem; what should receive the response in the nodes in front of the SYNC message?
It is better to ask my question more generally, what is the answer in front of the SYNC message?

Comment: @S.mSajjadi I don't understand what you mean with "nodes in front of the SYNC message". The SYNC message exists solely for PDO and control object synchronization between multiple nodes. Quite a handy feature too, in real-time control systems.

Comment: Exactly, I understood what you said; what section(s) in the network produces this message?